# Absolute value of sum of complex numbers all lying on a unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_{1}$ be $p$th root of unity and $z_{2}$ be $(p-1)$th root of unity then what is the absolute value of $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}(z_1)^{j}(z_2)^{j}$.

I tried goemetric sum but stuck. Also this should be $\sqrt(p)$

$p$ is an odd prime.

Comment: Is $p$ a prime?

Comment: Yes i have edited thanks

Comment: How did the geometric sum not work?

Comment: Absolute value of $\frac{1- x^{p-1}}{1-x}$

Comment: can you first double-check your sum and second specify which roots of unity you use as the answer seem to depend on that geometrically

Comment: @Conrad yes z1 and z2 should be primitive roots of unity of order p and p-1